# Pandas Decile Rank

Tags: pandas

I just used the pandas qcut function to create a decile ranking, but how do I look at the bounds of each ranking. Basically, how do I know what numbers fall in the range of the ranking of 1 or 2 or 3 etc?

Comment: Hello. You will have more luck getting answers to your question if you are able to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following python code with 2 short examples can help you. For the second example I used the isin method.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
    
        
    df = {'Name' : ['Mike', 'Anton', 'Simon', 'Amy',
                    'Claudia', 'Peter', 'David', 'Tom'],
          'Score' : [42, 63, 75, 97, 61, 30, 80, 13]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Name', 'Score'])
    
    df['decile_rank'] = pd.qcut(df['Score'], 10,
                                labels = False)
    
    print(df)

Output:
          Name  Score  decile_rank
    0     Mike     42            2
    1    Anton     63            5
    2    Simon     75            7
    3      Amy     97            9
    4  Claudia     61            4
    5    Peter     30            1
    6    David     80            8
    7      Tom     13            0
      

    rank_1 = df[df['decile_rank']==1]
    print(rank_1)
    
Output:
     Name  Score  decile_rank
    5  Peter     30            1
    

    rank_1_and_2 = df[df['decile_rank'].isin([1,2])]
    print(rank_1_and_2)
    
Output:
        Name  Score  decile_rank
    0   Mike     42            2
    5  Peter     30            1
```